# YouTube Authorization Code exchange fails with redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth, youtube, google-oauth

I'm trying to **exchange an authorization code for access code**, but I'm getting an error saying "**redirect_uri_mismatch**".

I waited ~8 hours just in case it needs to update, but no luck so far.

[The redirect uri's are set correctly, as you can see from the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNSrq.png)

**Initial Front-End redirect/request:**

```
GET => https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
    ?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
    &include_granted_scopes=true
    &state=state_parameter_passthrough_value
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/profile?platform=youtube
    &access_type=offline
    &response_type=code
    &client_id=[HIDDEN]
```

**After code is parsed, I exchange the code for access code:**

```
POST => https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
    ?client_id=[HIDDEN]
    &client_secret=[HIDDEN]
    &code=[HIDDEN]
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:2222/youtube/oauth
```

**Response:**

```
data: {
  error: 'redirect_uri_mismatch',
  error_description: 'Bad Request'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the **redirect_uri has to match the initial request's uri**.
Problem solved, feel free to upvote for visibility - thanks.

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3